# Repeating of rows in a javascript table

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a JavaScript function that receives a variable and displays a table. The table will have different output according to the variable. When the table loads for the first time everything runs smoothly. But if i send another variable to the function then the result will be the combination of the new table and the previous table.For examble if i run the function for the first time i will get the following result:

[image]

If i run it again sending a different variable the outpout will be:

[image]

The result now is the addition of the previous outpout plus the new one 
If i refresh the page and do it again i will get the result i want which will be:

[image]

Which is the result i want without having to refresh my page

The source code of my funcntion is the following:

```
<script>

function tableFile(input) {

var tblUsers = document.getElementById('tbl_users_list');;
var databaseRef =  firebase.database().ref().child(`files/${input}`)
var rowIndex = 1;

databaseRef.once('value',function(snapshot){
snapshot.forEach(function(childsnapshot) { 
var childKey = childsnapshot.key;
var childData = childsnapshot.val();
//var urls = childData.url;

var row = tblUsers.insertRow(rowIndex);
var cellId = row.insertCell(0);
var cellName = row.insertCell(1);
var button = row.insertCell(2);

var itd = document.createElement('input');
itd.setAttribute("type","button");
itd.setAttribute("value","View");
itd.onclick=function () {
window.open(childData.url);
};

cellId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.filename));
cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.created));
button.appendChild(itd);

rowIndex = rowIndex+1;
//document.write(username);

})


  });

}
//script for disaplying the data in the dolder of a spesific user, along with the displaying of a file inside the folder in a new window
</script>
```

Can someone please help me?
Thanks in regards

Comment: Replace the existing table row (if any), instead of appending new ones …?

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Try clearing the table on every tableFile() call. I mean, var tblUsers.innerHTML = ""; after var tblUsers = document.getElementById('tbl_users_list');

Comment: Please don't repost your question ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149236/duplication-of-rows-in-javascript-table) [or this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153028/display-data-from-firebase-database-using-javascript)). Instead see [How do i get attention for one of my questions without a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer).

Comment: Thanks man hopefully this would help