# Display Data from firebase Database using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a a table that has four columns ID,NAME,SURNAME and RECIPIENT

[image]

Each button has a  different value that is equal to the number of the ID that is in the same line as the button. For example the value of the first button is 2, second button 3 last button 123 all the buttons have id=contact. Each time i press a button i store the value of that button in a variable with the name input. My source code for that is:

```
var input; //prepare var to save contact name/ PLACE outside document ready
$(function() {
 // contact form animations
 $('button[id="contact"]').click(function() {
   input = $(this).val(); //set var contactName to value of the pressed button

    $('#contactForm').fadeToggle();

  })
  $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#contactForm");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.fadeOut();

    }
  });

});
```

Then i want to user this variable to fetch some files that are corresponded with the current varibale from firebase database. In my firebase database i have a folder with the name files that has three supfolders that coresponds to the values of the three buttons that i have [image]

In general lines I click one of the three buttons (let's say the button in the first column), I store the value of the button(so now the input value will be equal to 2). Then i drug all the information that is stored in firebase database from files/2/. I have implemented the source code for that but I am not getting any results and when i run inspect console i am not getting any errors. The source code is the following :

```
var databaseRef =  firebase.database().ref().child(`files/${input}/`);
var tblUsers = document.getElementById('tbl_users_list');

var rowIndex = 1;

databaseRef.once('value',function(snapshot){
snapshot.forEach(function(childsnapshot) { 
    var childKey = childsnapshot.key;
    var childData = childsnapshot.val();
    //var urls = childData.url;

    var row = tblUsers.insertRow(rowIndex);
    var cellId = row.insertCell(0);
    var cellName = row.insertCell(1);
    var button = row.insertCell(2);

    var itd = document.createElement('input');
    itd.setAttribute("type","button");
    itd.setAttribute("value","View");
    itd.onclick=function () {
        window.open(childData.url);
    };

    cellId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.filename));
    cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.created));
    button.appendChild(itd);

    rowIndex = rowIndex+1;
    //document.write(username);


    })


  });
```

If in the above source code change the line `` var databaseRef =  firebase.database().ref().child(`files/${input}/`); `` replacing the variable i stored the value of the button in the first function with 2 , 3 or 123 i am getting results so it seems the the problem is there but i dont know what else to do.

Can someone please help me ?
Thanks in Regards

Comment: I think the problem is, that ```var databaseRef =  firebase.database().ref().child(`files/${input}/`);``` is executed *before* you have set the variable `input`. But it's hard to tell, since it is not clear where your second code block resides within your application.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a perfect use case for the `.dataset` or `data-` attribute. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) has a great page showing how to use this.  Basically, store the uid as `<data-uid = "ach782bckhbc23whatever">` in your HTML on the `<tr>` or the `<button>` element an on click, use `evt.target.dataset.uid` or `evt.target.parentElement.dataset.uid` to get the row's uid to make your `.get()` firebase call.

> ```
> <div id="user" data-id="1234567890" data-user="johndoe" data-date-of-birth>John Doe</div>
>
> let el = document.querySelector('#user');
>
> // el.id == 'user'
> // el.dataset.id === '1234567890'
> // el.dataset.user === 'johndoe'
> // el.dataset.dateOfBirth === ''
>
> el.dataset.dateOfBirth = '1960-10-03'; // set the DOB.
>
> // 'someDataAttr' in el.dataset === false
> el.dataset.someDataAttr = 'mydata';
> // 'someDataAttr' in el.dataset === true
> ```